# Как получить данные поста

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть свой php файл как из него получить данные поста по его id?

Comment: [get_post()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post)

Comment: Ну либо раскройте детали, что за php файл, где он находится и так далее.

Comment: файл лежит в корне, я так понимаю надо как то подключить функции ворд пресса но не понимаю как это сделать

Answer (score 1):

> У меня есть свой php файл как из него получить данные поста по его id?

Чтобы что-то получить из ВП нужно вначале подключить ядро. Это делается так:

`require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );`

См [подробнее](https://wp-kama.ru/id_3014/podgruzhaem-sredu-wordpress-s-minimalnoy-nagruzkoy-konstanta-shortinit.html).

После этого уже можно использовать функции ВП. Для получения данных постов используется класс [`WP_Query`](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query) или обёртка над ним [`get_posts`](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts).